# How to use a scheduled reminder to alert an administrator when a membership expires?

Tags: tokens, scheduled-reminders

I want to set up a simple scheduled reminder that fires an email to an administrator (only - not to the expiring member as well) to alert them to the fact that a membership has just expired.

I'm assuming that if I limit the recipients to the named administrator then email will go only to that person and not to the expired member as well. Is that a correct reading of this functionality?

I also want to include in the email the name of the expiring member, so using a token, such as {contact.display_name} seems to make logical sense. However, will the token be replaced by the name of the expiring member, or by the name of the administrator?

Comment: have you considered CiviRules?

Comment: For the moment I've set up a report that gets emailed to the administrator. Better in some respects, but worse in others - for example the report will get emailed regardless of whether there are any expired members in the target time frame or not. CiviRules may well be more flexible.